# Underlined JLabel

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jlabel

I am trying to make a JLabel underlined.  I searched everywhere, but I got nothing.  Even in the properties, there is no option for underlining the JLabel.  What can I do?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<HTML><U>YOUR TEXT HERE</U></HTML>");
label.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
```

OR

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Underlined Label");
Font font = label.getFont();
Map attributes = font.getAttributes();
attributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON);
label.setFont(font.deriveFont(attributes));
```

Comment: Don't forget to close your tags!

Comment: @Clark it does not matter

Comment: @devaldcool, even if it doesn't matter, a good practice should be followed at the very least to create good habits. Careless coding is the path to the dark side. Careless coding leads to bad habits. Bad habits lead to broken code. Broken code leads to suffering.

Comment: @hfontanez i m sure after reading your comment that u safely remove pendrive before ejecting it or hold a fork with your left hand...life is easy dude..do not waste time on closing tags or safely removing pendrives and eat like u have never eaten before

Comment: Where should I put these code? `initComponents()` is not editable, I am using Netbeans 8

Comment: It is not necessary to close `<html>` tag. The doc use html text without closing the tag. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html   So I think it is totally acceptable.

Answer (score 38):

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Underlined Label");
Font font = label.getFont();
Map<TextAttribute, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>(font.getAttributes());
attributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON);
label.setFont(font.deriveFont(attributes));
```

Comment: +1. Also, label.getText() will now return the actual, intended text instead of HTML markup.

Comment: Better use `Map<TextAttribute, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>(font.getAttributes());` to avoid the compiler warning `unchecked call to put(k v) (...)`.