# Why underline not working?

Tags: java, swing

I wrote a simple code for underlining the text after enabling the toggleButton.
Reset of underlining will be actioned after disabling the toggleButton.
But I don't see the underlining?

Here is my code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.font.*;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;

public class UnderlineIt {
  private JTextPane textPane;
  private JToggleButton button;
  private Font font;

    UnderlineIt() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("underline");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(200,200));

        textPane = new JTextPane();
        font = new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD+Font.ITALIC, 18);
        textPane.setFont(font); 
        textPane.setText("underlined");


        button = new JToggleButton("underline it!");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if(button.isSelected()) {
                    Map attributes = font.getAttributes();
                    attributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON);
                    textPane.setFont(font.deriveFont(attributes));
                } else {
                    Map attributes = font.getAttributes();
                    attributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, -1);
                    textPane.setFont(font.deriveFont(attributes));
                }                                   
            }               
        });

        frame.add(textPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new UnderlineIt();
    }
}
```

But it won't work. Where is the mistake?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make my Jlabel underlined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15892844/make-my-jlabel-underlined)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code works fine if you use a JTextField instead of a JTextPane.

So I guess because JTextPane is designed to be used with style attributes that feature doesn't work.

You can use something like the following:

```
SimpleAttributeSet underline = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setUnderline(underline, Boolean.TRUE);
StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
doc.setCharacterAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), underline, false);
```

Comment: thank your for the note! Using different methods for the styling the text in JTextPane and JTextField? That really is annoying!

Answer (score 1):

You ought to just use html tags to underline your button text rather than go through the process of defining fonts, and maps and such.

```
if(button.isSelected()){
    textPane.setText("<u>Underlined text</u>")
} else {
    textPane.setText("Not Underlined");
}
```

that should be much easier...