# Java swing border error

Tags: java, swing, border

I am adding a java swing border into my existing code. I have referred online and put in my code which I got from a site, but on running it I get an error, and when highlighting in my intellij this pops up : cannot resolve symbol 'p'. Where am I going wrong ?

```
private class AnotherBorderTest extends JFrame {
    public AnotherBorderTest() {
        setTitle("Border Test");
        setSize(450, 450);

        JPanel content = (JPanel) getContentPane();
        content.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 2, 3, 3));


        p = new JPanel();
        p.setBorder(new MatteBorder(new ImageIcon("BALL.GIF")));
        p.add(new JLabel("MatteBorder"));
        content.add(p);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void main(String args[]) {
        new AnotherBorderTest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you didn't have any value assigned to variable *p*. Use code

```
JPanel p = new JPanel(); /* instead of p = new JPanel() alone */
```

as it *declares and assigns* the variable p of type **JPanel** with a value of object *new JPanel()*.

Comment: it has no errors now, but I am not able to see the border. The main thing I want is the words MatteBorder to appear as I intend to use it as a method of grouping various settings in the GUI.

Comment: I suppose adding the panel is most important, but I have never worked with them before, how would I create a new one ?

Comment: Can you add and see any other border? Do _p.setBorder([BorderFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html).createLineBorder(Color.black));_, does it produce a black border around your panel?

Comment: yes sorry , the border is there, but i need a new panel, just to illustrate some words, like the word Testing for example, and then an empty panel, but just the word is visible

Comment: and there is no new panel created, upon running the above code

Comment: In case you want multiple panels on the frame you could create multiple panels (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15694375/1737819) and put them to the mainPanel (so called _container panel_) then do `mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS)`.

Comment: Managed to get it using this code :  formBuilder.add(new DJLabel(LOGIN, login, KeyEvent.VK_N), cc.xy(1, 6));

Comment: One more question though, how do I underline the word LOGIN, I m getting stuck with it

Comment: If this DJLabel is a JLabel then see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15892859/1737819 where it says that you can put HTML code in your `JLabel label = new JLabel("<html><u>this text will be underlined</u><b>this text is bolded</b> and this text appears as it is</html>");`